# Best way to call multiple selected functions and save RAM

Tags: c++, arduino

I am writing this rather long program and i was having issues with strange behavior (most probably related with memory). So i decided to rewrite the whole project this time not using Strings and using malloc, strcpy  etc for better management of memory.

At this point I have created all functions needed and i need something to decide witch set of functions to call on each event based on the recognizeIncommingDataCode variable that I am feeding.

```
void identifyActionToPerform(int recognizeIncommingDataCode)
{
  switch (recognizeIncommingDataCode)
  {
    case 1:    //incomming phone call
    findIncommingNumber();
    processPhoneCall();
    if(reportsOnOffSetting)
    {
       if(checkRelayState())
        {
          sendStateReport();    //send state report
        }
        else sendErrorReport(); 
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    findIncommingNumber();    
    opperateRelays();   //opperate relay without state report except in case of error sendErrorReport
    if(reportsOnOffSetting==2)
    {
       if(!checkRelayState())
        {
          sendErrorReport();
        } 
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    findIncommingNumber();
    opperateRelays();    //opperate relay with state report
    sendStateReport();
    break;
    case 4:
    findIncommingNumber();    
    sendStateReport();    //send state report
    break;  
    case 5:
    findIncommingNumber();       
    sendSimReport();      //send sim report
    break;
    case 6: 
    findReportsOnOffAndStoteInEEPROM();      //turn reports on or off and save selection in eeprom     
    break;
    case 7: 
    findIncommingNumber();
    saveDefaultNumber();      //save default number to send state reports in eeprom 
    break;
//    case 8: 
//   // renewBalance();
//    break;
    case 9: 
    activateSMSChoice();
    break;

    default:    //irrelevant incomming sms
    break;      
  } 
}
```

My qustion is, is this a good way to perform this task or (concerning RAM memory) or i should create 9 separate functions that only contains the function calls for the specific task e.g

```
void case3(void)
{

    findIncommingNumber();
    opperateRelays();    //opperate relay with state report
    sendStateReport();

}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code demonstrates anything that would use any significant amount of memory. More likely your "strange behaviour" was related to errors in your code. Yes ***you absolutely should*** break your large function down into smaller ones *but with **meaningful** names*. E.g. Instead of `void case1()` rather use `void HandleIncomingPhoneCall()`. The stack space for an extra function call is minimal, but the improved readability and maintainability of your program will be huge.

Comment: PS: c and c++ are different languages with _some_ similar syntax. Which one are you using?

Comment: I spent quite some time looking for errors. All functions were working correctly on their own but once i put them together program would crash and restart the uC.
I used memory watching libraries and when those chain funtion call were happening i had readings of 100 bytes left on RAM and then crash.
Obviously the posted code is just a small part of the approx 1000 lines code.

Comment: Im using gcc compiler witch supports c++ but it also has compatibility for c.
Im using my code in c++

Comment: If you're writing c++ code, then the fact that your compiler supports c is irrelevant. Visual Studio supports: C, C++, C#, F# **and** Visual Basic (and can support other via additional tools). You shouldn't post VB code and tag the C language "just because VS supports it" in that case!

Comment: `"Crash" != "strange behaviour"` If you have a memory leak bug then yes, that can happen. Trying to rewrite using more error prone memory management features is not likely to help. (Though changing to use appropriate types rather than abusing strings should yield improvements.) You should still run a memory analysis tool to look for memory leaks.

Comment: I note that none of your functions return anything. That means all your functions operate on global data. That means the program can't handle two phone calls at the same time (and there may be cleanup problems). It could be better if the funcations pass a state structure around.

Comment: Sometimes it crashed and if i did some seemingly irrelevant changes it would not crash but still not work as intended.

Can you please elaborate a bit more about memory leaks and what is memory analysis?

I use Arduino IDE to write my code. It supports c, c++

Comment: Correct, some of these functions like findIncommingNumber() update global char arrays. I know its not the best thing to use global variables but they are not that many or that long(e.g.  findIncommingNumber() updates a 16 global char array. Rest of functions just take info from those the updated arrays from the arrays and perform tasks.

Comment: I have neither the time not inclination to use the comments section to present a course on "memory leaks". Google is your friend. As @PaulOgilvie pointed out: "there may be cleanup problems". You say "all functions were working correctly on their own" and that's precisely why global state is a problem.... `A()` works fine, `B()` changes state, and therefore `A()` behaves differently.

Comment: @Vangde Let me try state this as unambiguous and clear as possible: _You have bugs of various kinds in your original program. Rewriting your program won't help you learn anything. You'll probably just create different variations of the original bugs. Or you might produce some entirely new bugs. You need to learn to debug your program **properly** so you can understand what you did wrong and **fix the real problem** and avoid those mistakes in future. **Until then you're doomed to flounder with code that "looks like it works" but doesn't because you lack the skill to see the errors.**_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as stated the question is more of a coding style question (i.e. primarily opinion-based). The "how to save RAM" portion of the question could have removed the opinion based aspect, but the code does not reflect any memory pressures. In which case the code is irrelevant.

Comment: @CraigYoung I agree that there are many things to learn. I am doing the best a can by researching and asking for oppinions. But why are you so sure that it isnt a memory related issue? 
I didnt post the thousands of lines of code therefore you can not see something that creates memory pressure as you say since no one would even attempt to take a look let alone debug it for me.
What  im asking is about what is the correct practice for the simple thing im asking and what difference it would make relating the memory.

Comment: @Vangde I'm not saying it isn't a memory related issue. I'm saying you've shown no code to that effect. In fact I specifically pointed out that your original code "may have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) bug". Another level on a void function call without parameters will only add a few bytes. That's hardly likely to be relevant if you're not deallocating memory correctly. If you're failing to deallocate memory correctly using high level routines in your original code; you're even more likely to make the same mistake using low level routines like `malloc`.

Comment: @CraigYoung " Another level on a void function call without parameters will only add a few bytes." This is all what i wanted to know, thank you.
As for the malloc portion of you answer, yes i agree that it is harder and more prone to problems but according to my research is the correct way. The easy way is what i was using, (all Strings) witch i suspected that led to heap fragmentation and if that was the case it would still fail.

Comment: @Vangde I obviously don't know the memory profile of your program. At best I can assume the arduino tag implies tighter than normal constraints. But I still doubt your research that lead to the conclusion `malloc` "is the correct way". The fact that you seemed unfamiliar with _memory leaks_ but are aware of _heap fragmentation_ is somewhat surprising. Having "100 bytes left on RAM" is more symptomatic of leaks than fragmentation. Fragmentation is a problem when you have enough bytes for an allocation, but not enough _contiguous_ bytes. (Note: How you checked available memory may be relevant.)

Comment: @CraigYoung Correct, the device that im programming has 1.5kbytes of RAM. What i did to check the size of the available memory was to call from various places in my programm(typically at the start and the end of every function) a function that checks available RAM and printed it in theserial monitor). After the boot it reported about 650 bytes of free space but when i was giving orders to perform designed tasks that size was greatly reduced to about 100 bytes and then it would ether crash and restart or just do nothing, stopping even the main loop execution(depended on version of my program).

Comment: @CraigYoung Plus "100 bytes left on RAM" could also mean problem caused from nested functions, doesnt it?

Comment: @Vangde No function calls consume stack memory which has to be pre-allocated because it has to be contiguous. Concerns re stack are: deep recursion, and many bytes consumed as a result of arguments between method calls. If your stack is exhausted, you'll get an error this site pays homage to: stackoverflow. This can also crash your program, so it pays to identify the specific error that crashed your program. Hopefully there's something built-in to your toolset. Otherwise you could try return different error codes from the top level.

Comment: If your app suddenly drops from 650 bytes to 100 bytes: did you expect to allocate 550 bytes? Also first line/last line in a function is less important than before function call and after function call. If that dropped by 50 bytes on a call: you've lost 50 bytes. Probably to a global, but if not: then it's a leak. The reason I said "How you check is relevant" is that memory can be managed in layers. You need to check available memory at the correct layer; otherwise results can be misleading.

Comment: @Vangde Addendum on: "function calls consume stack memory which has to be pre-allocated because it has to be contiguous." That is perhaps an oversimplification because memory virtualisation does allow stack space to be allocated from physical memory incrementally. But even if your device does support that, it wouldn't perform a new allocation until the current reserve is exhausted. (As I mentioned earlier, memory management can be a large and complex subject worthy of an entire course.)

Comment: @Vangde One last thing before I sign off and leave you to figure things out. I notice that the arduino web site says: "The Arduino language is ***based on*** C/C++." (I.e. the c++ tag might also be incorrect.) But more importantly, my comments have been from a c++ and general programming perspective. I'm not even certain to what extent newer language features of c++ that allow better memory management are supported. Basically I may be wrong in some of my statements, and would need to do some investigation to know for certain. (So bear that in mind.) Either way... Good luck! I wish you success.

Comment: @CraigYoung Thank you very much for the help Craig! You have been a tremendous adviser. I wish i had talked to you before embarking to rewrite my code from scratch. I just finished it and the same exact error is there :(

Comment: Now im trying to remove pats of my program untill problem goes away so i can narrow it down :(

Comment: @CraigYoung C/C++ just means that it can be programmed purely on c or c++ or using both. Its not some new language called C/C++

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, go ahead and make them into separate functions.

If you are using any decent compiler, it will do stack frame optimizations and not more than return address size memory will be used on the stack.

Having said that stack frames' lifetime is only till the call return. So you are not really *wasting* any memory unless these functions recursively call themselves several times.

As to why they should be separated - It makes the code more readable and maintainable. As you can imagine the version you wrote above it incredibly ugly.

Finally if you are really worried about the memory it occupies on the stack, go ahead and mark the `case` functions as inline.

Comment: First o all thanks for the reply.

Now if i create the seperate functions i will still have to have another switch statement just like the above that it will have
`
  case 3:
    findIncommingNumber();
    opperateRelays();    //opperate relay with state report
    sendStateReport();
    break;
`

Comment: Yes, you would still need the switch case but it would be very clean `case 1: case1(); break; .. `. All the conditions etc inside the cases would be moved to the functions.

Comment: Having said that there is also a way to get rid of the cases. You can make an array of function pointers. The array can simply contain the corresponding functions at the appropriate indxes. Then you can index into the array using your recognizeIncomingDataCode variable and call the function. But it would be in no way more efficient that a switch case. A switch case would look better and will be easier to understand.

Comment: ...and `3` could have been defined as `#define INCOMING_CALL 3` to even add more clarity and be prepared for future changes.